# C++14 Async Task Scheduler

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, c++14, scheduled-tasks

I'm not sure if this site has the right audience for anyone to be able to respond to this, but I wrote a header only scheduler which schedules a task to be run in the future on another thread:

```
#pragma once
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>

class Scheduler
{
public:
    Scheduler();
    ~Scheduler();

    template<class F, class... Args>
    std::future<typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<F>::type(typename std::decay<Args>::type...)>::type>
    schedule(F&& f, Args&&... args);

    template<class F, class... Args>
    std::future<typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<F>::type(typename std::decay<Args>::type...)>::type>
    schedule_after(const std::chrono::steady_clock::duration& d, F&& f, Args&&... args);

    template<class F, class... Args>
    std::future<typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<F>::type(typename std::decay<Args>::type...)>::type>
    schedule_at(const std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point& t, F&& f, Args&&... args);

    void clear();

private:
    struct Task
    {
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point time;
        std::function<void()>                 func;
    };

    struct TaskComparer
    {
        bool operator()(const Task& left, const Task& right) const { return right.time < left.time; }
    };

    std::vector<Task>       mTasks;
    std::mutex              mMutex;
    std::condition_variable mCv;
    bool                    mExit;
    std::thread             mThread;
};

inline Scheduler::Scheduler()
    : mExit{false}
    , mThread{[&]
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mMutex};

            for(;;)
            {
                auto time = mTasks.empty() ? std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point::max() : mTasks.front().time;

                if(mCv.wait_until(lock, time, [&]{ return mExit || (!mTasks.empty() && mTasks.front().time != time); }))
                {
                    if(mExit)
                        break;
                }
                else if(!mTasks.empty())
                {
                    std::pop_heap(mTasks.begin(), mTasks.end(), TaskComparer{});
                    auto task = std::move(mTasks.back());
                    mTasks.pop_back();

                    lock.unlock();
                    task.func();
                    lock.lock();
                }
            }
        }}
{}

inline Scheduler::~Scheduler()
{
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mMutex};
        mExit = true;
    }

    mCv.notify_one();
    mThread.join();
}

template<class F, class... Args>
std::future<typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<F>::type(typename std::decay<Args>::type...)>::type>
Scheduler::schedule(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    return schedule_at(std::chrono::steady_clock::now(), std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<class F, class... Args>
std::future<typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<F>::type(typename std::decay<Args>::type...)>::type>
Scheduler::schedule_after(const std::chrono::steady_clock::duration& d, F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    return schedule_at(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + d, std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<class F, class... Args>
std::future<typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<F>::type(typename std::decay<Args>::type...)>::type>
Scheduler::schedule_at(const std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point& t, F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    auto func = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<F>::type(typename std::decay<Args>::type...)>::type()>>(std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    auto future = func->get_future();

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mMutex};
        mTasks.push_back(Task{t, [=, func = std::move(func)]{ (*func)(); }});
        std::push_heap(mTasks.begin(), mTasks.end(), TaskComparer{});
    }

    mCv.notify_one();

    return future;
}

inline void Scheduler::clear()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mMutex};
    mTasks.clear();
}
```

Questions:

- Is there any way to implement `finish` (block until pending tasks are done) without adding members/overhead? The user can do this now by storing all the returned `future`s and `wait`ing for them, but is that too burdensome?
- Is there a way to fix or improve the un-optimal/funky `bind`/`packaged_task`/`shared_ptr`/`lambda`/`function` setup for storing tasks without adding a whole lot of code? (really, I want a `std::unique_function` but it doesn't exist :() (test before recommending anything because I wound up with this solution because clang was crashing on me with some other setups)
- Should I take a `duration<Rep, Period>` or a `steady_clock::duration` (ditto for `time_point`)? Even if I hide the actual `duration` type behind type erasure, I still need access in order to do the compares for the heap. And how would you compare `time_points` from different clocks anyway? If there is a way to take any kind of duration I would prefer it, as that's what `condition_variable` does.
- Should you be able to specify how many threads it uses? Is it legitimate to *want* multiple threads? If so, should there be a `run` function the user can run on their own threads instead of this owning a thread (and/or `run_some`, blah!)? I'm not into adding things because someone might want it someday - I'm really unsure if it's legitimate to *want* this to use multiple threads, at least at this level; For example you could add tasks which just call `std::async` with another task to get the same effect.
- All the usual code review questions (general improvements, bug fixes, etc?)

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor:

```
    , mThread{[&]
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mMutex};

            // LOTS MORE CODE.
        }}
{}
```

Took me a moment to realize that this a lambda and a separate thread not the main thread. I think you can make this clearer by actually moving the code into a method or function so we can see that this is being run be a different thread.

You are not providing a guarantee that your `mThread` is going to enter the loop before you start scheduling jobs on the thread; is this going to be a problem? If not I would make some explicit comment to that affect.

Could use RAII here:

```
                lock.unlock();
                task.func();
                lock.lock();
```

Comment: Agreed about the lambda. I can change it to `[&]{ run(); }` and move the code to a private `run` function. Concerning RAII, it's all RAII-safe there (and there is no given construct to help anyway). `lock` is a `unique_lock`. Note I am `unlock`ing and re-`lock`ing, not the other way around which is the `lock_guard` case.

Comment: Concerning the guarantee, if you add a task before the loop gets started it won't matter. Personally I don't think it's important to call out all the random things that work unconditionally. If it did depend on some random timing (whether the thread entered the loop or you pushed a task in first) it would just be broken, IMO.

Comment: The unlock_guard is a commonly requested feature. Alredy in boost. https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/1850 I think it is worth wrapping anything that takes this pattern.

Comment: Well, there's probably a reason it didn't get into the standard. While you _need_ `lock_guard` to manage exceptions safely, there is no potential unsafety in not locking when you leave the scope from a thrown exception. Not that I'm particularly against it, but I'm not bringing in boost as a dependency for `unlock_guard`, and I'm not writing some boilerplate for it in this class either. I suppose it would save 1 line of code, heh.